# How to get a sub collection after using .where in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if there was a way of getting a sub collection after using .where

This is my database format

- Users    <-- collection
- Bob123
- posts   <-- sub collection
- post1

---

```
Firestore.instance.collection("Users")
.where("followers", arrayContains: id)  //id is the users id 
//He i want to get the collection of posts that the particular user has posted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subcollections are under an individual document, while a query identifies a group of documents. If when you know that the query only identifies one document, the Firestore client doesn't know that, and even if it did, it doesn't know the full path for that document.

You first need to execute the query, then get the individual documents, and then you can get the subcollection of each document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tring to do something similar -

Events -> widget.mydatahere (document) -> eventFood (subcollection) -> selectedFood (document in subcollection) -> selectedFoodRecipe (value of foodRecipe).

This will get it to work, however, the problem here that even setstate, won't update the ui, console logs fine, but ui don't update.

```
Future<String> loadmyFoodItem() async {

await Firestore.instance
    .collection('Events')
    .where("eventName", isEqualTo: widget.mydatahere)
    .getDocuments()
    .then((onValue){
  onValue.documents.forEach((f){

    Firestore.instance.collection('Events').document(f.documentID)
        .collection('eventFood')
        .where('foodName', isEqualTo: selectedFood)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result){

            selectedFoodRecipe = result.data['foodRecipe'];
            print("selectedFoodRecipe $selectedFoodRecipe");

      });
    });
  });
});

return 'ready';
}
```